# OpenLayers 4 Vector - append new features, but without clearing others

Tags: jquery, ajax, openlayers, geoserver

I'm using OpenLayers 4 with Gesoerver 2.12 WFS. I would like to add new features in every 1 second to the Vector Source and display on the map.

Now, my problem is that I can't add new features without the vectorSource.clear().

How can I add the new features without clearing the "old" features?

My code:

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=wfs_geom&propertyName=geometry,id2&sortBy=id2+D&maxFeatures=1&srsname=EPSG:3857&outputFormat=application/json"
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
 projection: 'EPSG:3857',
 format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
 url: url
});

var fetchData = function() {
 jQuery.ajax(url, {
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   //vectorSource.clear(); 
   console.log(data);
   vectorSource.addFeatures(data);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   console.log(errorThrown);
   }
 });
 updateTimer = setTimeout(function() {
  fetchData();
 }, 3000);
};
fetchData();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it. `vectorSource.addFeature(feature);` is the correct method.
However, it only accepts [ol.Feature](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Feature.html) objects, not raw data. The `format` option of the VectorSource only applies to loading via url, it is not used for `addFeatures`.

But transforming the data to features is easy:

```
var feature = new ol.format.GeoJSON()({ featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' }).readFeature(data));
vectorSource.addFeatures(feature);
```

or reading multiple features:

```
var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON()({ featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' }).readFeatures(data));
vectorSource.addFeaturess(features);
```

Comment: Thank you. And where to insert the lines you wrote? Just replace  vectorSource.addFeatures(data) with these?

Comment: @zsoooc yes, just replace that line